# JSON file that contains parenthesis as a key value

Tags: javascript, json, key, parentheses

I currently have a json file that looks like:

```
{
"Inventory": [{
        "id": "1",
        "StockNumber": "1000",
        "Make": "Ford",
        "Model": "F150",
        "Trim": "STX",
        "Year": "2011",
        "Color": "Red",
        "Cylinders": "8",
        "Transmission": "Automatic"
        "Gear_Ratio_(4x4)": "",
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "StockNumber": "1001",
        "Make": "Ford",
        "Model": "F150",
        "Trim": "Lariat",
        "Year": "2012",
        "Color": "Black",
        "Cylinders": "8",
        "Transmission": "Automatic"
        "Gear_Ratio_(4x4)": "4.56",
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "StockNumber": "1002",
        "Make": "Chevy",
        "Model": "Silverato",
        "Trim": "",
        "Year": "2020",
        "Color": "Red",
        "Cylinders": "8",
        "Transmission": "Automatic"
        "Gear_Ratio_(4x4)": "4.56",
    }]
```

}

My problem is, I have been unable to get the value for they key Gear_Ratio_(4x4).

I have tried:

```
$.getJSON(dataFile, function (data) {
  $.each(data.Inventory, function (index, value) {

        if (value.StockNumber === $("#productStockNumber option:selected").text()) {

          console.log("The Make is: " + value.Make);
          console.log("4x4 Gear ratio is: " + value.Gear_Ratio_(4x4));
        }
    });
});
```

This works:
console.log("The Make is: " + value.Make);

This does not work:
console.log("4x4 Gear ratio is: " + value.Gear_Ratio_(4x4));
Gives the error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

I have tried to escape the parenthesis, but that did not work:

console.log("4x4 Gear ratio is: " + value.Gear_Ratio_\(4x4\));

Changing the JSON may not be an option, as there are other keys that contain parenthesis, such as body dimensions for parts, and more.

Sorry if I missed the solution myself.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: `value["Gear_Ratio_(4x4)"]` — brackets (`[ ]`) allow access to object properties also

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution.  I thought I tried that as well at one point, but this works.